# Lua, Specify where to create files for io.open?

Tags: lua, directory

How can I put the file created by io.open somewhere besides the folder the lua file is in.

```
local test = io.open("Test.html", "w")
test:write("Hello world.")
test:close()
```

Comment: `io.open("/path/to/your/Test.html", "w")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoy simply supply a full path (or relative path) and not just a filename.

```
local test = io.open("c:\temp\Test.html", "w")
```

Comment: I doubt you can find this file on disk :). Escape `\`.